# No signal / KVM switch

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, display, kvm-switch

I have a VGA KVM 2 port switch running a Win. 7 & Win. 10 computers through. The Win. 10 computer shows no signal when I start up the computers. The Win. 10 computer is a gaming computer that I want to use for music editing etc. & it has the same resolution (1920-1080 as the Win. 7 computer. What can the problem be? The Win. 10 computer works fine when just connected directly to the monitor. I have gone through 3 KVM switches so far.

Comment: are you using any adapters like DisplayPort->HDMI or vice-versa? if so, are they "active"? many KVMs won't work with passive adapters. does the video cable meet the specs of the KVM (resolution and refresh Mhz)?

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm not using any adaptors or HDMI. Resolution is the same as the Win. 7 computer that works.

Comment: just for fun, try swapping the video cable between the two systems, and see if the situation remains the same. that will at least isolate the source of the problem to the win10 system, presuming the issue doesn't just reverse itself, in which case we know its the cable currently on the win10 system.

Comment: What is the made/model of the KVM switch with your setup? or as you stated, you already tested 3 KVM switches, what are the made/model of them?

Comment: This comment is to simply lend a humble suggestion. I suggest that this page might be something to consider: "Why You No Longer Need a KVM Switch for Multi-PC Setups" ••• https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-you-no-longer-need-a-kvm-switch-for-your-multi-pc-setup/ ••• There are several free virtual tools to perform exactly what a physical switch does, from your keyboard and mouse... but without the hassle of a physical box and cables. These can be downloaded, ran and tested within minutes of reading this comment. Night work with headless PCs also. Kind regards to you and yours.